# Store the result of `show create procedure procedure_name` into a variable in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to get the code used to create an existing procedure by using the command
`show create procedure`  and then store it in a variable. All this inside a procedure.

#### Problem

- `Set @var` for creating user defined variables only works when the result contains one row and one column.
- `show create procedure proc_name` returns multiple columns and I cant select the specific one which is `Create Function`

#### Question

How can I save the code for creating a procedure into a variable for later use.

Comment: Why do you need it? You could do it easily in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the routines table in the information_schema database.

```
select
routine_definition
from
information_schema.routines
where
specific_name = 'nameOfYourStoredProcedure'
```

For more information see this [link.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/routines-table.html)

UPDATE:

Then you will have to build it yourself. There's no other way.

```
select
CONCAT('CREATE PROCEDURE nameOfYourStoredProcedure ', routine_definition, 'END') /*something like that, this here is pseudo-code*/
from
information_schema.routines
where
specific_name = 'nameOfYourStoredProcedure'
```

UPDATE 2:

Considering Devart's comment, you will have to also use the parameters table from information_schema database.

Note: This table was added with MySQL 5.5.3

For more information have a look [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/parameters-table.html)

I honestly don't know of any other way to solve this. Also I can't update to 5.5.3 here to help you. Good luck.

Comment: There is a difference between `select routine definition` and `show create procedure`. I wanted the actual code used to create the procedure and not the procedure itself.

Comment: @tombom There are also procedure parameters and other options.

Comment: @cWoDeR Updated my answer again.

Comment: @tombom I actually do not understand why cWoDeR wants to do it. I'd do it in the application. Another point - this question may be a result of bad database design.

Comment: @Devart Actually I have no clue either. Simply can't imagine why anyone would need that.

Comment: @Devart I am trying to document and improve on the procedures of a certain database. So I take the procedure name, code, parameters e.t.c put it in a new DB add comments, a description of the procedures action e.t.c and then I improve on the procedures while showing the original procedures and my progress of improving the procedures until its the most optimum. I dont know if I am making sense.

Comment: OK, try to join `information_schema`.`parameters` (from MySQL 5.5) or `mysql`.`proc` table to add parameters to the output.

Comment: @devart I see, I will try see how that will work. In the meantime I just used output from routine_definition column

Answer (score 0):

below snippet should work for most cases, i started working on it hoping it will be simple enough.
but there are many issues to address,and exceptions.

i guess using SHOW CREATE / MySQLDump is still a better solution (even thoughit does not allow reading response into variable).

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS(' ',
        'DELIMITER $$\n',
        'CREATE ',
        CONCAT_WS('=',r.SECURITY_TYPE,CONCAT_WS('@',CONCAT('`',SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.`definer`,'@',1),'`'),CONCAT('`',SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.`definer`,'@',-1),'`'))),
        '\n',
        r.ROUTINE_TYPE,
        CONCAT_WS('.', ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME),
        CONCAT('(',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PARAMETER_NAME, p.DTD_IDENTIFIER)),')'),
        IF(o_p.DTD_IDENTIFIER is not null,CONCAT('RETURNS ',o_p.DTD_IDENTIFIER),''),
        ROUTINE_DEFINITION,
        '$$') stmt_
```

FROM
    information_schema.routines r
        LEFT JOIN
    information_schema.parameters p ON p.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = r.routine_schema
        AND p.specific_name = r.routine_name
        AND p.PARAMETER_MODE = 'IN'
        LEFT JOIN
    information_schema.parameters o_p ON o_p.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = r.routine_schema
        AND o_p.specific_name = r.routine_name
        AND o_p.PARAMETER_MODE IS NULL 
WHERE
    ROUTINE_SCHEMA IN ('_secured' , 'tester')
GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('.', ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME)